# xUnit issue instantiating a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, xunit

Im trying to test that my controller returns a ViewResult, but I'm having an issue creating the instance of my controller.

This controller, called MySampleController uses in the constructor the file /Config/sample.config but when I execute the tests from the UnitTest project, I get an error cause is searching the sample.config in "bin/sample.dll.config" on UnitTest project instead use the one on my Website.MVC/bin.

This is my project structure:

```
Website.MVC

--> /Controllers/MySampleController.cs

--> /Config/sample.config

Website.UnitTests

--> /Controllers/MySampleControllerTests.cs
```

Here my unit Test created with xUnit.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// All tests related with MySampleController
    /// </summary>
    public class MySampleControllerTests
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks that view model cannot be null
        /// </summary>
        [Fact]
        public void ActionResult_Is_Not_Null_On_Index_Action()
        {
            //arrange
            var controller = new MySampleControllerController();
            //act
            var result = controller.Index();
            //assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);
        }
    }
```

How this kind of issues are normally resolved?

Thanks in advance

Regards.

Jose.

Comment: So in `MySampleControllerController` constructor, you're using `/Config/sample.config` ? Is it hard coded or what ?

Comment: Yes is harcoded, the pity its that its a piece of code that i cannot change. Its into a external dll... Any idea?

Comment: Can we see code in `Index` action ?

Comment: Just returns a ViewResult: return View(), thats all.

Comment: Well one way around is to create `MySampleControllerController` constructor that will accept parameter, just for testing purposes. This way you can `Mock` dependency that you have in your constructor. Just it's really hard to say for sure, without seeing parameterless constructor code. Could you post it ?